# Prevent a form submition, check records with Ajax and if there are records continue ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently listening to a form submitting on one of my views and it's checking for records. What I want to do is if there are records allow the form to actually render the view and if not just show the error page. Obviously the "else" where the continue code is suppose to be it's empty.. Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Here's the JS function that actually intercepts and posts to AJAX.

```
    $('form#search-form').submit(function (evt) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<%: Url.Action("Details","SpecialtyTrack") %>',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.results == 0) {
                    $('#error').fadeOut('fast');
                    $("#error").fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else {
                    $('#error').hide();

                };

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
        evt.preventDefault();

    });
```

and Here's my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string searchParameter)
    {

        var sP = this.spRepo.findSpecialtyTrack(searchParameter);
        try
        {
            var record = sP.FirstOrDefault();
            ViewData["directoryID"] = record.DirectoryArtItem.DirectoryCanvass.DirectoryEdition.DirectoryID;
            ViewData["directoryName"] = record.DirectoryArtItem.DirectoryCanvass.DirectoryEdition.Directory.Name;

            return View(sP);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {

            return Json(new {
                results = 0
            });
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Response.StatusCode = 500 in your catch and it will trigger the error callback in jQuery's ajax call. Then you can handle the error however you want where you have that alert.

```
public ActionResult Details(string searchParameter)
{

    var sP = this.spRepo.findSpecialtyTrack(searchParameter);
    try
    {
        var record = sP.FirstOrDefault();
        ViewData["directoryID"] = record.DirectoryArtItem.DirectoryCanvass.DirectoryEdition.DirectoryID;
        ViewData["directoryName"] = record.DirectoryArtItem.DirectoryCanvass.DirectoryEdition.Directory.Name;

        return View(sP);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return Json(new {
            results = 0
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it as 2 actions 
one as validation part/ other as ajax request if it must be

```
<% using Ajax.BeginForm("ValidateAction",new AjaxOptions{ UpdateId="HolderWhereSubmitButtonWillBe"}){
%>

validation page
<%}%>
```

response from your ValidateAction returned as partial view

```
<div id="HolderWhereSubmitButtonWillBe">
here will be the ajax call code and button to submit via ajax(all as partail view send as reponse for validation
</div>
```

Also i would add something like

if (!modelstate.isvalid) return view()

just to make sure